# filling in a form with a cookies

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

I have a form that allows a user to enter their username and password into my site. I'm looking for a way to have the email part automatically filled in if a cookie I set was found.

On one page I have -

```
<?php
  setcookie("email", $email, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
?>
```

This sets the cookie

On the login page I have this -

```
<tr><th><p>Email:</p></th> <td><p><input type="text" name="strEmail" maxlength="40"
value="<?php print($strEmail); ?>"/></p></td></tr>
```

How can I fill in the email only if the cookie was set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line above that input:

```
$strEmail=isset($_COOKIE['email']) ? $_COOKIE['email'] : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="strEmail" maxlength="40" value="<?php if (isset($_COOKIE["email"])) echo $_COOKIE["email"]; ?>"/>
```